# kendo editor link is not clickable

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-editor

I am trying to use kendo-editor with angular. Every other feature is working except the insert link. As I insert a link, it's not clickable though it adds the anchor tag properly. And also is there a way to change contentEditable value in kendo editor

```
<kendo-editor #kendoeditornote formControlName="note"  ( (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" style="height:200px;width:550px">
                        <kendo-toolbar class="ProseMirror" [overflow]="true" contenteditable="false">
                            <kendo-toolbar-buttongroup >
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorBoldButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorItalicButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorUnderlineButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorStrikethroughButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorAlignLeftButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorAlignCenterButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorAlignRightButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                                <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorAlignJustifyButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              </kendo-toolbar-buttongroup>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorCreateLinkButton ></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-colorpicker kendoEditorForeColor></kendo-toolbar-colorpicker>
                              <kendo-toolbar-colorpicker kendoEditorBackColor></kendo-toolbar-colorpicker>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorUndoButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorRedoButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist  kendoEditorFormat ></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorCleanFormattingButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist kendoEditorFontSize></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
                              <kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist  kendoEditorFontFamily ></kendo-toolbar-dropdownlist>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorInsertUnorderedListButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorInsertOrderedListButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorIndentButton></kendo-toolbar-button>
                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorOutdentButton></kendo-toolbar-button>

                              <kendo-toolbar-button kendoEditorUnlinkButton></kendo-toolbar-button>

                        </kendo-toolbar></kendo-editor>
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of what you tried?

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example on stackblitz?